# page numbering style chapterwise

Tags: page-numbering, thesis

I have, say, 10 chapters in my thesis and say each chapter has 20 pages each. I am strangely getting page numbering each chapter, i.e. 1-20, then again 1-20 like that. Could anyone tell me how to avoid this and continuously get a page numbering?

```
\documentclass[thesis,a4paper,12pt]{ucdThesis}
\makeindex
\title{A}
\author{B}            
\copyrightYear{C}     
\graduationMonth{D}
\supervisor{ Professor XYZ}
\numberOfCommitteeMembers{1}
\coSupervisorA{ Prof TRS} 
\keywords{}
\headSchool{} 
\major{EEE}
\degree{Doctor Of Philosophy}
\college{Engineering and Architecture}  
\dept{Electronic \& Electrical Engineering}
\university{University College Dublin}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{12mm}
\let\plll\lll 
\let\lll\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}
\usepackage[scale=.95,type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[cochineal,bigdelims,cmintegrals,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[zerostyle=c,scaled=.94]{newtxtt}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\raggedbottom
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[inactive]{srcltx}           
\usepackage{relsize}                
\usepackage{booktabs}               
\usepackage{mathrsfs}               
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap/fncychap}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[ruled, noend, noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts, MnSymbol}
\SetNlSty{}{}{.}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb,setspace,amsthm,calrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pstool,psfrag}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wela}
\usepackage{wedn}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

\parindent0mm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{\rule{.4\textwidth}{4\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 128, 128}
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=myblue,urlcolor=myblue,citecolor=myblue,}
\newcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{myblue}}
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{myblue}(#1)}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\textit{\leftmark}}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Front Matter}{rootNode}
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Title}{a}
\makeTitlePage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\makeCopyrightPage
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Dedication}{b}
\include{dedication} 
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Acknowledgements}{c}
\include{acknowledgements}
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Quote}{d}
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Abstract}{e}
\include{abstract}
\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Table of Contents}{f}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor={myblue}}
\tableofcontents 
}
\addToTOC{List of Tables}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor={myblue}}
\listoftables 
}
\addToTOC{List of Figures}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor={myblue}}
\listoffigures
}
\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Nomenclature}{g}
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{chapter7}
\include{chapter8}
\include{chapter9}
\include{chapter10}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}
%\makenomenclature
%\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}
%\printnomenclature[1.25in] 
%\makebiBliographyPage
%\include{nomenclature}
%\makebiBliographyPage
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{references/references-dissertation} 
%\makeAppendixPage  
%\appendix
%\include{appendix-1}
%\addToTOC{Vita}
%\include{vita}
%\nomProf{}
%\numberOfCommitteeMembers{4}
%\committeeMemberA {Committee Member 1} 
%\committeeMemberB {Committee Member 2} 
%\committeeMemberC {Committee Member 3} 
%\committeeMemberD {Committee Member 4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check your chapter files for `\pagenumbering` -- that restarts from 1.  Another command that has that effect is `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am not sure what are you talking about, could it be possible for you to tell me if I need to remove or include something.

Comment: I don't know the `ucdThesis` document class, but it's highly unusual to reset the page numbering for each chapter.  You don't show any preamble in your example code, so if that's shown completely, the page number must be reset in your chapter files.  So look in those files for something that will do that.  Some commands that might do that are `\pagenumbering`, `\mainmatter` or `\setcounter{page}`.  If you find such a command, remove it.  Otherwise, we don't have enough information to help.

Comment: In those chapter.tex file nothing is there related to page count

Comment: I have now included everything I am using